# Trying to convert column to be row indexes, set_index error

Tags: pandas

```
data_new. set_index('Usual Mode of Transport to Work')
```

[jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3e6Kz.jpg)

Trying to convert column to be row indexes, however, it shows up as NaN? How do i resolve it? Thanks. Im a beginner in python.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with a toy dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5,size=(5, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
print(df)
```

```
   A  B  C  D
0  3  1  2  1
1  2  2  3  4
2  2  4  4  1
3  1  0  3  2
4  1  2  4  0
```

Now, let's set column `A` as the index

```
df.set_index('A')
```

```
   B  C  D
A         
3  1  2  1
2  2  3  4
2  4  4  1
1  0  3  2
1  2  4  0
```

This sets the index correctly but doesn't save this newly indexed dataframe in the original data frame variable, i.e., `df`. So when you check the value of `df` you see find the original dataframe.

To save the new indexing, you can do one of the following

```
df = df.set_index('A)
```

or

```
df.set_index('A', inplace=True)
```

Coming to the `NaN` values, I believe it has got something to do with using Jupyter notebook. Since Jupyter allows jumping between cells, it does not necessarily follow the linear execution order like traditional coding. This can get confusing. You can use the "Variable View" in Jupyter to cross-check if you are passing the value you intend to. I hope this can help you figure out the `NaN` issue.